# gactions CLI crashes on Windows when uploading google actions

Tags: sdk, action, actions-on-google

I created a project dawai-5555, and a json action file dawai.json as described in Google's doc https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/define-actions .
When I try to upload it using the Windows (I tested both 32/64bit versions) gactions command line tool from google, I get the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
        panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x4ebc99]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction.func1(0x110c191c)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:478 +0x1f6
panic(0x69e0c0, 0x8685f8)
        /usr/lib/google-golang/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0x1d0
github.com/Jeffail/gabs.(*Container).Bytes(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x4000106)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/Jeffail/gabs/gabs.go:459 +0x19
github.com/Jeffail/gabs.(*Container).String(0x0, 0x11139da0, 0x6d902d)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/Jeffail/gabs/gabs.go:483 +0x21
main.getLocaleFromActionPackage(0x110a3d48, 0xd, 0x110a3d48)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/gkaldevrel/cli/gactions/gactions.go:605 +0xba
main.commandUpdate.func1(0x110f3860)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/gkaldevrel/cli/gactions/gactions.go:726 +0x1b3
reflect.Value.call(0x67d940, 0x6effbc, 0x13, 0x6d89ad, 0x4, 0x110c1900, 0x1, 0x1, 0x110c18c4, 0x6d2920, ...)
        /usr/lib/google-golang/src/reflect/value.go:434 +0x723
reflect.Value.Call(0x67d940, 0x6effbc, 0x13, 0x110c1900, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x5ac617, 0x6d8aa9)
        /usr/lib/google-golang/src/reflect/value.go:302 +0x7f
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x67d940, 0x6effbc, 0x110f3860, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:487 +0x114
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x6d90c3, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x6eb16e, 0x4b, 0x0, ...)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/command.go:191 +0x875
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0x110de410, 0x110c8000, 0x7, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:240 +0x462
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAndExitOnError(0x110de410)
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:257 +0x43
main.main()
        /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/gkaldevrel/cli/gactions/gactions.go:157 +0x75d
```

Am I the only one to face this issue ?

Thanks for your help.

F.

Comment: Having the same problem on Linux:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591266/go-panic-when-using-gaction-to-update-google-home-assistant-package  .  Just posted a tweet to the Twitter Google actions account.  Maybe you should too: https://twitter.com/actionsongoogle

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem on my MAC laptop. Can anyone post an older version of gactions SDK?

Answer (score 1):

While trying, just now, to start the command again, an update has been launched and a new version (2.1.1) seems to fix the problem.
Thanks to Google support for having fixed this quickly.

F.