# Golang runtime panic when using gaction on Linux to update Google Home/Assistant package?

Tags: json, go, google-cloud-platform, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to build my first Google Home app using the instructions in this tutorial, on a Linux 14.04 LTS box (not Windows):

```
https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-your-first-action-for-google-home-in-30-minutes-ec6c65b7bd32
```

The deployment of my app to Google Cloud succeeds.  However, when I get to the section where you test your app with the simulator, the following *gactions* commands fail with the message "No help topic for preview/simulate"

```
$ gactions preview --action_package action.json --invocation_name "three doors" --preview_mins 1234

No help topic for 'preview'
```

And:

```
$ gactions simulate

No help topic for 'simulate'
```

I then tried switching to the Google Actions instructions for the simulator here:

```
https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/simulator
```

That document instructs me to use the following command to upload my Actions project:

```
$ gactions update --action_package action.json --project three-doors-9898
```

But that leads to a Golang panic crash with the following stack trace:

```
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference [recovered]
    panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x506df6]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction.func1(0xc4200fd208)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:478 +0x27a
panic(0x737b00, 0x960720)
    /usr/lib/google-golang/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0x283
github.com/Jeffail/gabs.(*Container).Bytes(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3000100)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/Jeffail/gabs/gabs.go:459 +0x26
github.com/Jeffail/gabs.(*Container).String(0x0, 0xc420123350, 0x793672)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/Jeffail/gabs/gabs.go:483 +0x2b
main.getLocaleFromActionPackage(0xc4203a60a0, 0xb, 0xc4203a60a0)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/gkaldevrel/cli/gactions/gactions.go:605 +0xdf
main.commandUpdate.func1(0xc42008cf00)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/gkaldevrel/cli/gactions/gactions.go:726 +0x209
reflect.Value.call(0x717fa0, 0x7a9988, 0x13, 0x793011, 0x4, 0xc4200fd1c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc4200fd150, 0x788860, ...)
    /usr/lib/google-golang/src/reflect/value.go:434 +0x906
reflect.Value.Call(0x717fa0, 0x7a9988, 0x13, 0xc4200fd1c8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x614896, 0x7930f1, 0x4)
    /usr/lib/google-golang/src/reflect/value.go:302 +0xa4
github.com/urfave/cli.HandleAction(0x717fa0, 0x7a9988, 0xc42008cf00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:487 +0x17a
github.com/urfave/cli.Command.Run(0x793732, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7a4928, 0x4b, 0x0, ...)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/command.go:191 +0x9fd
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).Run(0xc420001080, 0xc42000e0c0, 0x6, 0x6, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:240 +0x57d
github.com/urfave/cli.(*App).RunAndExitOnError(0xc420001080)
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/urfave/cli/app.go:257 +0x53
main.main()
    /usr/local/google/home/gkal/code/go/src/github.com/gkaldevrel/cli/gactions/gactions.go:157 +0xa02
```

Below is my package file (*action.json*), which I did validate with a JSON validator:

```
{
    "versionLabel": "1.0",
    "agentInfo": {
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "projectId": "three-doors-9898",
        "voiceName": "male_1"
    },
    "actions": [{
        "description": "Launch intent",
        "initialTrigger": {
            "intent": "assistant.intent.action.MAIN"
        },
        "httpExecution": {
            "url": "https://us-central1-three-doors-9898.cloudfunctions.net/three_doors"
        }
    }]
}
```

How can I fix this and get my Google Home/Assistant app working?

**UPDATE**: The version of *gactions* I am using came from here:

I used the *Linux/x86_64* link on this page to get it:

https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli  .

Is it possible that's the wrong version for my system?  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit version.

Comment: Can you send the version of gabs.go that matches this stack trace?  The code at https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs/blob/master/gabs.go doesn't seem to match.

Comment: Or at least the 10 or 15 lines of context around line 459

Comment: @JohnWeldon I did a whereis for "gaction" and can't seem to find it.  Is it possible that it's inside an archive? (like a JAR file is to Java)?  Also, please see my comment to your Answer.

Comment: Ah, are you saying that you are not modifying this code (i.e. that it's not your code): https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs/blob/master/gabs.go ? In that case yeah it's probably a bug in gactions

Comment: @JohnWeldon Ouch.  I hope not.  Not much I can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new gactions version available. Try `gactions selfupdate`.

If that's not working because the version is broken, download the [old version](https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli) and run it. This old version then updates to 2.1.1 and everything works again.

Comment: That fixed the problem.  I heard from the Actions group at Google on Google+ that they indeed post a fix recently and your command pulled it down, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My surmise is that `github.com/gkaldevrel/cli/gactions/gactions.go:605` is calling `.String()` on a nil pointer to `gabs.Container`

The github.com/gkaldevrel/cli package doesn't seem to be public, so I can't tell for sure, but tracing through the stack trace and extrapolating from the different version of gabs.go at https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs/blob/master/gabs.go, it appears the `gabs.Container` has a `func (g *Container) Bytes` method that is trying to dereference `g` and is panicing because it's nil.

Comment: It sounds like your saying that I may have a bad version of gactions?  I used Linux/x86_64 link on this page to get it: https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/gactions-cli  .  Is it possible that's the wrong version?  I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64-bit version.

Comment: Not knowing how gactions works I can't tell if it's in gactions or in your code, but the fix in your code would be to check that `g` is not nil before dereferencing it in the `func (*Container) Bytes()` method. (If my deductions are correct)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not in my code.  I've never written a line of Go in my life and the Google Home project itself is all JSON and Javascript (Node.js).

Comment: In that case it's sounding like a bug in the package you're trying to use yeah. :(

Comment: Looks like it's a real problem.  Just found this post by Windows devs with the same problem, so it's happening on Linux & Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574621/gactions-cli-crashes-on-windows-when-uploading-google-actions