# How to fix: "No help topic for 'preview'" error when using gactions?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I've been trying to follow a tutorial on building your first action for google home:

```
https://medium.com/google-cloud/building-your-first-action-for-google-home-in-30-minutes-ec6c65b7bd32
```

I was able to deploy my application to the google cloud, but once I try to deploy my action.json test file I receive an error message that says: "No help topic for 'preview'."

```
./gactions preview --action_package action.json --invocation_name "three doors" --preview_mins 1234

No help topic for 'preview'
```

I've followed the suggestions from:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591266/golang-runtime-panic-when-using-gaction-on-linux-to-update-google-home-assistant
```

But updating gactions didn't work either as there were no new updates.

I'm running ubuntu-18.04.2  Linux 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64

```
{
  "versionLabel": "1.0",
  "agentInfo": {
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "projectId": "three-doors-3124",
    "voiceName": "male_1"
  },
  "actions": [
    {
      "description": "Launch intent",
      "initialTrigger": {
        "intent": "assistant.intent.action.MAIN"
      },
      "httpExecution": {
        "url": "https://us-central1-three-doors-3124.cloudfunctions.net/three_doors"
      }
    }
  ],
 "locale": "en"
}
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem, so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could your question be a duplicate of ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46591266/golang-runtime-panic-when-using-gaction-on-linux-to-update-google-home-assistant

Comment: @Kolban I read through that question and it seems to be similar, but the solution didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is from 2017, and a lot of the development environment and setup has changed since then. I'd recommend going to the [codelabs](https://developers.google.com/actions/codelabs/) as they will provide good up to date starting guides.